# \tcolorboxenvironment and color: Unwanted vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, color, tcolorbox

I'm using the package `ntheorem` to define theorem-like environments and  `\tcolorboxenvironment` (from the `tcolorbox` package) to frame them. I have a problem when I want to color the body of a theorem with `\color`: vertical spacing is added at the end, which is unwanted. This doesn't append if I don't frame the theorem with `tcolorbox` (or, of course, if I don't use `\color`).

Here is a MWE (see the extra space at the end of the first theorem):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor, ntheorem, tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\slshape}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem*{Thm}{Theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{Thm}{left=2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{Thm}
\color{red} 
\lipsum[2]
\end{Thm}

\begin{Thm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Thm} 
\end{document}
```

Would you have any solution? (I don't want to define my theorems through the library `theorems` of `tcolorbox`.)

Comment: Why not using the `theorem` library of `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mainly because the arguments of the theorems are not the same as standard `amsthm`/`ntheorem`... and I get lost when switching between documents using theorems from `tcolorbox` and documents using `ntheorem`.

Comment: I found `ntheorem` however never really convincing...

Comment: Well... to be honest I started using it just a few days ago. Until a few months ago, I used `amsthm` (sometimes with `thmtools`), then I tried `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `colupper=red` if all of the `Thm` environments should use this red color.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor, ntheorem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\slshape}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem*{Thm}{Theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{Thm}{left=2mm,colupper=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{Thm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine, as I intended in my document! I added a `\normalcolor` in the `\theoremheaderfont`, so that the header is not colored (which wasn't visible in my MWE...).

Answer (score 2):

Just use braces (because usually we use `color` like `{\color{<color>} <content>}`.

```
{\color{red}
\lipsum[2]}
```

or better

```
\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[2]}
```

[image]

Comment: It does work for the MWE... however, I initially intended (in my bigger document) to put the `\color` command inside the `\theorembodyfont` (so that it apply to all the `Thm`).